# How to prevent ordering certain products - or a category - from a specific country

Tags: magento

I have a category dedicated for exported goods , obviously , they will not be sold locally . so , how can I prevent customers who are from my country from ordering products that are meant only for exporting.. and showing an error message .. please help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that you will have to create a new product type.  You'll need a new module (use Daniel's excellent kick-start extension: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Daniel+Nitz/extension/1108/modulecreator) and then have your model extend `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Simple`.

Then, add a new attribute for your new product type to capture Allowed Countries, and implement the `isSalable` method in your Model to check for Allowed Countries.

This is not trivial, but it should be the right approach.  The guys at Inchoo (who write a great blog) have a good tutorial on the process: [link text](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-create-a-new-product-type-in-magento/) and in fact they've provided the shell of the module.

Good luck!
JD